# Lightning Throwing Error when conditionally rendering component in an iterable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

The idea of this component is to display the mini record view for a user when their image has the cursor on it. I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null" error whenever I hover over some of these.

I'm thinking I need to somehow give the client-side controller a unique ID of where I want to render the mini layout, "{!v.body}". At least, that's what I think I need to do - I'm not sure how this would get communicated to the controller.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="NewUserGridController">
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/jQuery_2_1_1_Js "/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="users" type="NetworkMember[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="renderSpan" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cX" type="String" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cY" type="String" default="true"/>
    <div class="container">
        <table >
            <tr >
                <td>
                <aura:iteration indexVar="i" items="{!v.users}" var="user">
                    <a href="{!'/community/s/profile/'+user.Member.Id}">
                        <img src="{!user.Member.FullPhotoUrl}" id="{!user.Member.Id}"
                             onmouseover="{!c.renderRecordView}" 
                             onmouseout ="{!c.unrenderRecordView}" 
                             height="75" width="75" alt="{!user.Member.FirstName}"/>
                        <span class="tooltip" aura:id="container">
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.renderSpan}">
                                {!v.body}
                                <!--force:recordView recordID="{!user.Member.Id}" type="MINI"/-->
                            </aura:if>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </aura:iteration>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
    ({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {    
        console.log('doInit new user grid');
        helper.getNewUsers(component);      
    },

    renderRecordView : function(component, event){    
        console.log(event);
        var id = event.target.id;
        var container = component.find("container");
        var x=event.clientX;
        component.set("v.cX", x);
        var y=event.clientY;
        component.set("v.cY", y);
        $A.createComponent(
            "force:recordView",
                           {
                               recordId: id,
                               type: "MINI"
                           },
                           function(newRecordView) {
                               if(component.isValid()){
                                   var body = component.get("v.body");
                                   body.push(newRecordView)
                                   component.set("v.body", body);
                               }
                           });
        component.set("v.renderSpan", true);
    },

    unrenderRecordView : function(component, event){    
        console.log(event);
        var id = event.target.id;
        var x=event.clientX;
        var y=event.clientY;
        component.set("v.body", '');
        component.set("v.renderSpan", false);
    },
})
```

Comment: is this method executed properly on mouseover `renderRecordView`.
 
and  `component.get("v.body");` i am not seeing any variable named with this.